# why does {0..1} work in for loop, but 'length=$#-1 {0..length}' not work?

Tags: bash

I want to print messages entered through the terminal, so I defined a function called `print`. But when I ran this script, I got such error message:

```bash
./hello.sh: line 17: {0..1}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..1}")
```

I changed the expression `{0..$(( $#-1 ))}` to `{0..1}`, and the scripts ran successfully, but after I changed it back, the same error emerged again. Can anybody tell me the reason behind it? My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

args=("$@")

length=$(( $#-1 ))

function print() {
    echo $@
}

for i in {0..$length}
do
    print ${args[$i]}
done
```

I changed the expression `{0..$(( $#-1 ))}` to `{0..1}`, the scripts ran successfully, but after I changed it back, the same error emerged again. Can anybody tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: That's working as designed. Take a look in the section `Brace Expansion` from `man bash`.

Comment: variable expansion happens after brace expansion in shell